# Multiline text with ellipsis doesn't work in FF and IE but in Chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser, xpages

I want to cut a long text up to three lines withing a DIV control.
It works perfect in Chrome but does not in FF and IE.
Here is my xPage:

```
<xp:div id="mainDiv" styleClass="style1">
    <xp:div id="contentDiv" styleClass="style2">
        <xp:div id="descriptionDiv" styleClass="style3">
            sssss sdf asdfasdf asdf
            asdf lasdkfl asdjfld asjlfkj
            asdlfj lasdjf asdkflasdkfjlk asdjfa
            asldflk sjalfkj
            asdlkfjl asdkjflasdkj flkasdjf lasdkjfl kasjdf klj
            sdfsdaf asdfasdf asdlfksd asdlkfj daslfjl asjfl sdjakl
        </xp:div>
    </xp:div>
</xp:div>
```

And here is css:

```
.style1 {
    display:            inline-block;
    vertical-align:     top;
    height:             244px; 
    width:              359px; 
    min-width:          359px;
    padding-top:        20px;
    padding-bottom:     20px;
    margin:             10px;
    border:             1px solid #c9c9c9;
}

.style2{
    padding-left:       20px;
    padding-right:      20px;
}

.style3{
    display:            block;
    display:            -webkit-box;
    height:             18 * 1.4 * 3;
    margin:             0 auto;
    font-size:          18px;
    line-height:        1.4;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow:           hidden;
    text-overflow:      ellipsis;
}
```

And here is what I got. How to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-line-clamp: 3
```

this option work only webkit browsers, like chrome, safari, opera etc. Reference [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=line-clamp)

Here you can read how to decide this another ways [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)